# Google Charts: HTML entities in NumberFormat prefix

Tags: html, google-visualization

I'm trying to get the UK GBP symbol (£) to show up correctly in my Google Chart's table but I'm finding that HTML entities seem to be automatically escaped.

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    prefix: '&pound;',
});
```

The above example literally shows `&pound;` in the table rather than showing up as the correct symbol.

Is there any way to get it to show up as it should be?

Previously I tried just using `prefix: '£'` but it was making the pound symbol show up as a blank square instead. I then searched and found another stackoverflow question suggesting that the person use the straight UTF-8 value -- in this case it becomes `prefix: '\u00A3'` which is quite unreadable.

I've just discovered that using the pound symbol directly works if I make sure my Javascript file is set to be encoded as UTF-8, but I'm still interested in general as to how you would get HTML entities to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want regular HTML entities to show up, you have to set the Table's "allowHtml" option to true.

Edit:

To clarify, "allowHtml" only works on Tables and OrgCharts.  The SVG/VML-based charts (Area, Bar, Bubble, Candlestick, Column, Gauge, Geo, Line, Pie, Scatter, Stepped Area, Timeline, and Treemap) don't support HTML entities; you have to use the unicode value for the character.

Comment: ... or whatever chart type it is, if it is not a Table chart.